# Understanding Random Variables as a function

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm trying to understand random variables. From my understanding, you have a sample space, $S$. Within $S$ there are values or events ($\zeta$) which can be used to map a function, $X$.

$X$ is a function, which is a function of zeta.

Question 1:
**$S = \{1, 3, e\}$, where $X(1) = 0, X(3) = 3, X(e) = 0$**

Find the events for $\{X=0\}$ and $\{X=3\}$.

$\{X=0\} = \{1,e\} , \{X=3\}=\{3\}$

Is my answer correct?

Question 2: **You have a four sided die, $S=\{1,2,3,4\},X(\zeta) = \zeta/2$**.

Find the probability of $P(\{X=6\})$ and $P({X\in \{0,1\}})$

For $P(\{X=6\}) = P(\{\zeta/2 = 6\})=P(\{\zeta= 12 \})= 0 $.

This makes sense as there is no $12$ on the four sided die.

$P(\{X\in\{0,1\}\}) = P( \{\zeta/2\in\{0,1\} ) = P( \{\zeta\in \{0,2\} )= P(\{0,2\}) = 1/4$

There is only a $2$ on the die, $1/4$ probability.

Do my answers look okay?

Comment: Your answers are ok if you know that the probability distribution of $X$ is [discrete uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution), i.e. every atomic event have the same probability.

Comment: @Masacroso Oh, indeed, we've *assumed* the four-sided die was unbiased (aka fair).

Comment: Yes @GrahamKemp, my wording was bad... I wanted to say *assume* instead of *know*. Anyway my comment is not important for the problem and can be completely ignored, it is just an attempt to expand the awareness of the OP in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to understand random variables. From my understanding, you have a sample space, $S$. Within $S$ there are values or events ($ζ$) which can be used to map a function, $X$

$S$ is a set of *outcomes*, which can be mapped to a set of real values by the function. $X: S\mapsto \Bbb R$.

> Question 1: ... Is my answer correct.

Yes.  $\{ζ \mid X(ζ)=0\} = \{1, e\}$, and $\{ζ\mid X(ζ)=1\}=\{3\}$

> Question 2: ... Do my answers look okay?

Yes, the look okay. Well reasoned and correct.